# Ctrl-C kills whole line while Ctrl-Z doesn't

Tags: shell, job-control, jobs

I am running multiple commands on the command line separated using semi-colons:

`cmd1; cmd2; cmd3`

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the above, it would kill all commands instead of just the one which is executing currently.

```
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$ ls
test1  test2
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$ cat; ls
cat is running
cat is running
^C
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp
```

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> would only suspend the current process and continue with the next one.

```
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$ ls
test1  test2
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$ cat; ls
cat is running 
cat is running
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
test1  test2
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$
```

Why is there a disperancy in behaviour, and is there any way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> behave like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

I'm actually running a server through tmux session as follows `node app.js; $bash`, and when I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill the server, it kills bash as well. I want to return to shell. Is there any alternative to achieve the behavior I want?

[UPDATE]

`tcsh` behaves the same with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. It would always act on all commands just as bash is doing with onlt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. But bringing back the job with `fg` would only bring back `cat` and not `ls`.

```
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$ ls
file1  file2
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$ cat; ls
cat is running 
cat is running
^C
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$ cat ; ls
cat is running
cat is running
^Z
Suspended
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$ jobs
[1]  + Suspended                     cat
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$ fg
cat                                     // Pressing ctrl-d here to exit cat
[kartika@vm-kartika-vnc ~/junk]$
```

System Information:

```
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$ uname -a
Linux kartikpc 3.13.0-70-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 16 18:34:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
kartik@kartikpc:~/junk/exp$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Does `grep SigIgn /proc/$$/status` have the 4 bit on in the lowest position? That's often the case. Then you can type Control-backslash to send a SIGQUIT to kill the foreground job without making the shell discard the rest of the command line. But it may produce a core dump of the foreground job, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 6):

You need to look up bash job controls. There is a decent explanation here: http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html

But in a nutshell <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will kill the commands (all of the line) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will background the running command. In your case it is backgrounding `cat` (supresses output and halts processing) and then continuing on to run the `ls` command.

You can confirm this by checking the process list and you will find your `cat` is still in the list.

To bring that job to the foreground look into the `fg` command.

Comment: I'm actually running a server through tmux as follows `node app.js; $bash`, and when I do a ctrl-c to kill the server, it kills bash as well. I want to return to shell. Is there any alternative to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Is there any way to suspend a whole multi-line command that is separated using a semi-colon?

Answer (score 0):

If that `node ...;$bash` thing is being *pushed* into the pty input buffer by `tmux`, then a possible solution is to configure the terminal appropriately, to `trap` terminal interrupts in such a way that only affects the interactive shell, and to use newlines rather than `;`.

```
stty noflsh; trap : INT
```

^that should handle the first two requirements.

The difference between a `;` and a `\n` is due to the way shells read input - a `;` semicolon is equivalent to a newline in that it delimits command lists, but it differs in that it does not delimit read input. For example:

```
prompt$ cat; echo something
```

---

```
this the cat process
this the cat process
^C
prompt$
```

---

But because I've configured the tty driver *not* to flush the input buffer on receipt of an interrupt with `stty noflsh`:

```
prompt$ cat^Jecho something
```

---

```
this is the cat process
this is the cat process
^C
something
prompt$
```

---

`bash`'s `readline` will actually display a literal newline for the key-combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> rather than the escape shown above, but the effect is the same: when the shell itself effectively ignores interrupts but its children do not, you can execute interrupted *lines* of tty input in serial so long as the terminal itself does not discard interrupted input entirely.